# How to add a vector notation above a variable name composed of multiple characters?

Tags: unicode, julia

In Julia it is possible to add Unicode characters with LaTeX like syntax. All allowed unicode characters can be found [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/unicode-input/). For example, it is possible to add a right arrow over a character with this simple code

```
F\vec[TAB]
```

and it produces the following character

[image: F with right arrow over it]

But I couldn't find a syntax to add the same right arrow over a whole word as `\vec` seems to always add the arrow over the previous character and does not allow to group them. For example

```
force\vec[TAB]
```

produces

[image: force with right arrow over the e only]

Does the syntax for this feature exists ?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I doubt it. Julia uses unicode "characters", that while they have a concept of "modifiers", they know nothing at the level of a whole word. For the output, for ex. in charts, you can obviously use LaTeX...

Comment: Can you use bold characters instead? Personally, I prefer that for vectors over the arrow notation.

Comment: Indeed, Julia has bold characters with `\bf<letter>` which are also commonly used for vectors and matrices. I guess this is the best option available.